# Making an iframe inherit cookies from the parent in Safari

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe, safari

My web app extends a Google Form's functionality by loading it as an `iframe`, and doing other stuff outside the `iframe`. If the Google Form requires authentication, Google makes a "Sign In" box appears within the `iframe`. When a user clicks on the button, a new tab opens, and the user is re-directed to the form in the new tab.

If a user navigates away from my web app, the extra functionality will obviously not work. So, what I am looking for is: to have an **authenticated Google Form load as an `iframe` within my web app**.

1. I can make the user first sign in via Google Sign-In (OAuth) on my web app and then load the `iframe`. On Chrome and Firefox, the `iframe` automatically starts with a logged-in session. This is great! But, this solution doesn't work on Safari. Is this related to [Safari blocking third-party cookies](https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/)?
2. If I want this functionality to work within Safari (and other such browsers), how would I go about doing it? Will I have to use the [Storage Access API](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/)? If yes, can you broadly tell me how to do it?
3. For now, I could just ask users to download Firefox/Chrome if they want to use my web app. Most of my users are Chrome users anyway. But, is implementing these privacy measures a part of other browsers' roadmap too? If yes, I may as well try and build a solution that will work in a year or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I expect so.
2. This needs to happen in the iFrame, so Google rather than you need to implement it.
3. Yes, but not until [2022](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/01/building-more-private-web-path-towards.html), so I would hope Google forms will support this by then.

Comment: 2. OK, so, the iframe's cookies are third-party cookies. And, because third-party cookies cannot be stored on the system, the authentication doesn't work on Safari. Is that a fair understanding?

As Alphabet Inc, unlike Apple, has a lot of web properties and embeddable content, it is quite likely it will figure out how to allow first-party cookies to be accessed by the ```iframe```s. Is that a fair hope?

Comment: The first part is fair, I think they will implement Apple’s solution, but not until all their web apps support it first.